# new Array() casting as object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

This is very strange, but my new array seems to be cast as an object...

```
var report = [];

console.log('Report type: ' + typeof report);
```

This produces the results: `Report type: object`, and I've confirmed it in Chrome, Firefox, and IE.

I've also tried using `var report = new Array()`, and other variations, like `var report = new Array('1', '2', '3')`. So far, they all produce the same results. I feel like a new JavaScript developer again... what in the world am I missing here?

FYI, my real end goal is to convert some JSON data to an array so I can filter the results using ng-repeat in my Angular application, since filter apparently doesn't work on objects. So if you have an answer for this part, please feel free to share.

Comment: Googling "javascript typeof array" would have provided you all the information you needed instead of cluttering up SO with another such useless question -- and before anybody tries to flag this question, down-vote reasons include not showing research effort, and being useless

Comment: strange you think an array isn't an object

Comment: Wow - thanks for the help, guys. It may not seem like it, but I did in fact Google this for some time, just not in those terms. I really appreciate the community support. Jeez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has always been the case. From MDN:

> // use Array.isArray or Object.prototype.toString.call
>
> // to differentiate regular objects from arrays
>
> typeof [1, 2, 4] === 'object';

I don't know much about angular specifically, but an array is always `typeof [] === 'object';` so just try to use it like normal.

Comment: Ah - apparently I've never needed to distinguish at this level before. I guess I still am a new JavaScript developer. =P

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your code is right, the reason why is because arrays are not a native type, arrays are actually objects that uses numbers as their keys,

true way you can verify if is an array is by using instanceof instead of type:

```
[] instanceof Array
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `typeof`array is `'object'` angular has utilities built in to check also

```
angular.isArray()
angular.isObject()
```

These are just 2 of the many utilities always visible at the top left of the docs site ... spend some time going through the whole docs site

[Angular functions docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function)